# SSIS Transform Component: Large Scale Data Storage

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm developing an SSIS Transform component that will need to store the contents of the incoming data stream and then output the data at a later point in time. This could be a large number of records with many fields (of any data type).

For example, this type of storage would be needed if you were developing a 'Sort' component, where you cannot output a single record until all records have been input.

My question is - what is the recommended practice for storing this temporary data? The Microsoft and Codeplex examples I've seen are somewhat trivial in that they use in-memory structures. I would like to avoid this, as this would seem to be a very bad idea when working with large data sets.

Is there a mechanism in the SSIS library to do this? **[okay, it looks like there is not]**

I'm considering a few options:

- Store the data on disk in a stream,
  keeping the record offsets into this
  stream in memory. During the output
  phase, I'll use these offsets to
  locate the desired record.
- Store the
  data in an ADO or OLEDB data source
  of the user's choosing.
- Other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - there is no 3rd-party accessible "buffering" mechanism exposed in the API.  You're responsible for it yourself, including paging to disk or whatever mechanism you choose to avoid storing all of the rows in memory.

Comment: Too bad. Any suggestions for alternate options?